# Dotcms Detail Page not found

Tags: dotcms

I have a content type for which I have specified a detail page and URLMapPattern but for the URL pattern the detail page 404 found error occurs. 
The detail page also exists.

**Detail Page: //demo.dotcms.com/Platform-Technology/Promotions/promotion-details**

**URL Pattern: /Platform-Technology/Promotions/{urlTitle}**

And on the content the following  tag has been added:

but in browser for Platform-Technology/Promotions/demo-promotion-1
Page not found **404 error**

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that could cause this problem, most likely related to the details of how you've implemented either the URL Maps themselves, or how you're attempting to access the URL Mapped content URL.

1. Make sure that you have a URL Title field in the content type, and that the Velocity variable name of that field is "urlTitle".

   - If the Velocity variable name doesn't match, you'll get a 404.
2. Make sure that the content in question has a value of "demo-promotion-1" for it's URL Title field.

   - If the content item doesn't have this value in the "urlTitle" field, you'll get a 404.
   - I'm not sure what you're referencing when you say your content has a tag value, but tag fields are not used with URL maps.
3. When you attempt to access the URL of the URL-mapped content, try doing it using the IP address of the server (e.g. "http://x.x.x.x" or "http://localhost").

   - It seems that you haven't changed your Host from the default of "demo.dotcms.com", and depending on how you're accessing the URL, you may be accessing the actual dotCMS demo site (http://demo.dotcms.com) instead of your local host (and if you're doing this, you'll always get a 404, since your content doesn't exist on the actual dotCMS demo site).

If none of this helps, I suggest you provide more details (such as your full Content Type field list, your full Content Type properties, and the full properties of the content item, and the full URL you're using including the leading "http://").  And considering posting in the dotCMS community forum, since there are more active dotCMS users there who may be able to help.